# Signature method in Inspect module for python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to run a Python 3 library in Python 2. It uses `inspect` module and `signature` method which is not implemented in Python 2 version of the module.

```
signature = inspect.signature(initializer)
```

There is no implementation in `__future__` that can help (at least, I haven't found one).

How can I replace this method?

Answer (score 7):

Package [`funcsigs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs) on PyPI is a backport of [PEP-362](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) (which adds signature introspection) to Python 2.6+. So change the line in question to

```
import funcsigs
signature = funcsigs.signature(initializer)
```

Answer (score 1):

`inspect2` is backport of the entire Python 3.6 `inspect` module to Python 2.7. Like `funcsigs` it is also available from PyPI, and `inspect2` is more recently maintained. (As I'm writing this, `inspect2` was last updated in 2019, while `funcsigs` was last updated in 2016.)