# How to properly get default keyword arguments for decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I'm applying a decorator to some functions, and the decorator would require some arguments in the functions. Yet, I would assign some default values to the arguments. The decorator receives the arguments with `*args, **kwargs`.

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        # do something with the required1 and required2 ...
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def foo(self, a, b, required1=0, required2='x'):
        pass
```

But calling the function in differernt ways the decorator wrapper would receive different argumets

```
A = MyClass()
A.foo(1, 2, 3, '4') # 1
A.foo(1, 2) # 2
A.foo(1, 2, required1=3, required2='4') # 3
```

The outputs would be like such:

```
#1 
args: [<object at 0x0000>, 1, 2, 3, ‘4’]
kwargs: {}
#2
args: [<object at 0x0000>, 1, 2]
kwargs: {}
#3
args: [<object at 0x0000>, 1, 2]
kwargs: {‘required1’: 3, ‘required2’: ‘4’}
```

How am I supposed to do if I want to access the required arguments like `r = kawrgs[‘required1’]` no matter the way of calling the function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for but maybe keyword-only arguments help solve your problem? `def foo(self, a, b, *, required=...)` Then these arguments cannot be passed as positional arguments.

Comment: It looks like it banned the #2 way of calling the function. But I still cannot access the arguments for #1 and #3 in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to solve this problem in one of my projects. And the only way I found is to use introspection of python.

Here is the code:

```
bound_args = inspect.signature(fn).bind(*in_args, **in_kwargs)
bound_args.apply_defaults()
target_args = dict(bound_args.arguments)
```

its binding income arguments of the function (either it comes with keywords or not) to the defined names of the function

Comment: It works well in Python 3. But in Python 2, it seems like the inspect doesn't have a signature module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946051/signature-method-in-inspect-module-for-python-2